# How to include a swagger file path externally in cloud formation yaml aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swagger, aws-cloudformation

How do we include a local machine path instead of the S3 bucket path to include the url of a swagger file in a cloud formation yaml.

The yaml file where I have included the local swagger file path is -

[image]

However, in the aws documentation and everywhere I searched , I get that we need to give upload the swagger in s3 bucket and then give that path like -

```
Fn::Transform:
  Name: AWS::Include
  Parameters:
    Location: s3://MyAmazonS3BucketName/MyFileName.yaml
```

Reference -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html

I realize that once on aws server, aws won't be able to locate our machine file.
Is there a way to include or upload the swagger file simultenously via cli command and not including the swagger body in your cloudFormation.yaml file .

My cli command is -

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name justatemplate --template-body file://E:/Documents/swagger.yaml  --no-verify-ssl  --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

Comment: This is not possible, but you first upload the file to S3 and later use it in the template, let me know if you would like an assistant with that

Comment: Oh ok...........

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SAM, this is possible just by referencing the local file path. Check out the code [here](https://github.com/matt-tyler/simple-node-api-split-lambda/blob/e42c544a016880db4de86e1baa58cae4bfa4e75d/template.yaml#L22-L26).